# i want to find the mean of a column from several files in R

Tags: r

this is my code, which gives NA for any input. Please help me know where am I going wrong.(I am a beginner)

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id=1:332){
  fname <- sprintf("%s/%03d.csv", directory, id)
  ldf <- lapply(fname, read.csv)
  df <- unlist(ldf)
  a <- matrix(df, ncol = 3)
  dfa <- data.frame(a)
  colnames(dfa)<-c("date", "sulfate", "nitrate")
  mn<-mean(dfa[, pollutant],na.rm=TRUE)
  print(mn)
}
```

Comment: Better do not use `print()` to return a value from a function.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually you want:

```
fname <- sprintf("%s/%03d.csv", directory, id)
ldf <- lapply(fname, read.csv)

my.mean <- function(df, pollutant) mean(df[, pollutant], na.rm=TRUE)

pollutant <- "nitrate"  # or "sulfate"
sapply(ldf, my.mean, pollutant) # or
mean(sapply(ldf, my.mean, pollutant))
```

Alternativly you want

```
mean(unlist(sapply(ldf, '[[', pollutant), na.rm=TRUE))
```

Comment: Hey! actually i want one mean of the column pollutant from all the files. The above code gives me mean of the column for each individual file.

Comment: @SONALIJHA I edited my answer. Please comment on the changes.

Comment: In case the files are different lengths, `sapply` will return a list, and `mean(sapply(ldf, '[[', pollutant), na.rm=TRUE)` throws an error. I think you need also and unlist to take care of that: `mean(unlist(sapply(ldf, '[[', pollutant)), na.rm=TRUE)`. If we knew that all the files were the same length, then of course the mean of the concatenated means would simpluy be the mean of individual file means

Comment: @dww Thanks for the comment. You are right. I will edit my answer.